# SSH remote invocation of local script + logging in realtime

Tags: bash, logging, jenkins, ssh, file-descriptor

I'm trying to remotely invoke bash script using Jenkins [Publish Over SSH plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin). After copying files I can run provided bash script.

When I use it this way:

```
/path/script.sh argument1 argument2
RETVAL=$?
exit $RETVAL
```

Script works, I can see logs (stdout and stderr) but after script ends it hangs till timeout. I've read that it is because of opened descriptors. I tried this one:

```
ACTLOG1=/path/logfile.log
/path/script.sh argument1 argument2 > $ACTLOG1 <&-
RETVAL=$?
cat $ACTLOG1
exit $RETVAL
```

It stopped hanging but I can't see logs in the realtime. Runnings script takes about 15 minutes, so for 15 minutes I see a loading circle and then all the logs displays together.

Is there a way to see logs in realtime and to avoid hanging?

If it's possible I'd like not to edit `script.sh`.

Comment: If you were to post the contents of this script, it might be possible to change it so that it doesn't hang when you use it the first way.

Comment: Not an option. 10 files, hundreds of lines + invoking an old, large server application. :/